Для чего нужно вызывать конструктор родительского класса в дочернем классе?
Правильно ли я понимаю что parent::__construct() нужен для того, чтобы в дочернем классе был доступ к свойствам объявленным в родительском классе ?
Вот пример из книги по PHP 8 Котерова, Симдянова


для чего в дочернем классе конструктора снова указывать те же параметры что и в родительском $title, $content ?

parent::__construct() нужен для того, чтобы выполнить код родительского конструктора в детском конструкторе, если он есть.

Ну да, всё просто: если вы не вызовете конструктор родителя, то не увидите в потомке тех полей, которые создаёт родитель в своём конструкторе. Потому что их просто никто не создаст. Это во всех языках которые я знаю так. Ну и если ещё какие-то свойства и методы потом дальше на эти поля завязаны, соответственно они тоже не будут работать. Поэтому хороший тон - вызывать в потомке конструктор родителя. Ну, кроме случая, когда вы за него сами всю работу сделаете по инициализации, хотя это и странно с точки зрения ООП. Но такое тоже бывает.

@CrazyElf "не увидите полей которые создает" весьма странный выбор слов, который автора может ввести в заблуждение. Видимость полей регулируется модификаторами видимости. В конструкторе поля не создаются, а инициализируются начальными значениями

@teran Да согласен, не чётко сформулировал. Конечно, речь про инициализацию.

Поясняю. Если говорить вообще, то конструктор нужен не только для того, чтобы назначить переданные в него значения свойствам класса. В нем может быть куча кода, помимо присвоений. Вот чтобы выполнить этот код в конструкторе потомка, и нужно вызывать родительский. Если же говорить про данный конкретный пример, то вызывать родительский конструктор не обязательно. Но желательно, поскольку там может в последствии добавиться некая логика.
